# Print Pascal Pattern

Tags: pascal

Please Help me out to print this pattern and also explain logic behind it. THank you in advance.

```
      0
    111
  22222
3333333
```

My Pascal Code is:

```
program patnum;
            uses crt;
            var
               row, col1, col2, totalRows, totalCol: integer;
            Begin
                 clrscr;
                 totalRows := 3;
                 totalCol := totalRows-2;
                        for row := 0 to totalRows do
                        begin
                                for col1 := 0 to totalCol do
                                begin
                                   write(' ');
                                end;
                                totalCol := totalCol - 1;  
                                for col2 := 0 to row do
                                begin
                                   write(row);
                                end;
                        writeln('');
                        end;
                 readln;
            End.
```

*** Please Help ***

Comment: Can you suggest me how do I come to possess good coding skills?

Comment: You can improve your coding skills by reading tutorials like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/ and by programming easy logic yourself. If you really want to be a good coder you have to play around with code, experiment and search some new tasks which you can solve.

Answer (score 0):

im sure there is a much more easy way to do this but if you just want to get it done with a good effort this should help.

```
 var
    t : integer       
 begin
    t := 6
    for x := 0 to t do
    begin
       write(" ");
    end;
    write("0");
    writeln;
    t := 4;
    for x := 0 to t do
    begin
       write(" ");
    end;
    write("111");

    writeln;
    t := 2;
    for x := 0 to t do
    begin
       write(" ");
    end;
    write("22222");
    writeln;
    t := 0;
    for x := 0 to t do
    begin
       write(" ");
    end;
    write("3333333");
 end.
```

Answer (score -1):

This really seems a programming exercise. However, here it is:

```
Program patnum(output);

function digitNumber(n:integer) : integer;
var counter : Integer;
begin
    counter := 0;
    while n >= 1 do
    begin
        counter := counter + 1;
        n := n div 10;
    end;

    digitNumber := counter; 
end;

procedure prettyPrint(x1 : integer; x2 : integer; x3 : integer; x4 : integer);
var Counter, max, tmp : Integer; 
Begin

    max := digitNumber(x1);

    tmp := digitNumber(x2);
    if(tmp > max) then
    begin
        max := tmp;
    end;

    tmp := digitNumber(x3);
    if(tmp > max) then
    begin
        max := tmp;
    end;    

    tmp := digitNumber(x4);
    if(tmp > max) then
    begin
        max := tmp;
    end;


    tmp := max - digitNumber(x1);
    For Counter := 1 to tmp do
    Begin 
        write(' ');
    End; 
    writeln(x1);

    tmp := max - digitNumber(x2);
    For Counter := 1 to tmp do
    Begin 
        write(' ');
    End; 
    writeln(x2);

    tmp := max - digitNumber(x3);
    For Counter := 1 to tmp do
    Begin 
        write(' ');
    End; 
    writeln(x3);

    tmp := max - digitNumber(x4);
    For Counter := 1 to tmp do
    Begin 
        write(' ');
    End; 
    writeln(x4);
End;



begin
  prettyPrint(22,3333,1,534);
end.
```

I would suggest using an array to hold the values to be printed but I leave that to you...

Also, your code seems almost useless.

*edit: Note that the function fails on integers < 1.

Comment: Thank you A. Rama, I am new to pascal programming, however my task to print the pattern,the good you give not working in Turbo pascal. What is good compiler?

Comment: Ok, I corrected the few mistakes there were, all because it has been 20 years since my last pascal program :D Couldn't you have corrected them yourself? Anyway, I used http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm to test my code this time around, I don't have a pascal compiler since ages ago.

Comment: I tried but it wasn't working, I try this code and thanks for your advice. Pascal is pretty old, there are rare sources on the internet.

Comment: It is working and I can't vote because it requires 15 reputation.